# What do the different colors of meta tags mean?

Tags: discussion, tags

Normal SF&F tags are all one color (blue with a lighter blue background):

[image]

But ***META***.SF&F tags are all over the place:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What do the different colors (text and background) mean?

Comment: Dark grey is one of the four compulsory tags that have to be on every Meta question. Red is a special tag that can only be applied by diamonds, IIRC, [featured] is the most notable example of that.

Comment: Strange; your images show a difference in colour between the [meta-tag:featured] and [meta-tag:faq] tags, which I can't see when looking at the tags on my screen. AFAIK, the only differences in colour are those described by Alex.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor: They have very slightly different background colours (not sure if that is intentional), but I doubt they can be distinguished if not right next to each other. For the screenshot above, I suspect the pointer might have been hovering over [tag:featured] when it was taken.

Comment: As a note, there's a key at the bottom of the [tags page](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/tags).

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the legend on the [/tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/tags) page, we see the following key:

- **[red: moderator-only-tag]**

  > this is a moderator tag, it can only be added by a diamond moderator.

  This includes tags like “faq”, any “status-XYZ” on feature requests and “community-ads”.
- **[dark grey: required-tag]**

  > this is a required tag; every new question must have at least one required tag.

  Namely “discussion”, “bug”, “feature request” and “support”.
- **[light grey: tag]**

  > this is a standard tag; every question must have at least one tag.

  These are analogous to the tags on SFF.se – they can be created, added and removed by any user (subject to rep requirements around tags/editing).